# No sounds in iOS Simulator but actual device no issue

Tags: ios, audio

My apps runs fine on actual device with sounds but on the iOS simulator, no sounds.
It was ok like few weeks ago and suddenly, it becomes mute for no apparent reason.

I am using the late 2013 Mac Pro.

So far, I have:
(a) Resetted the IOS sim
(b) Multiple restarts and rebuild
(c) Done the preference thng for Sound Effects to enable 'Play User Interface'
(d) Plug in and out for testing with external speakers or headphones

I must also add that this only happen when using the Mac Pro. My Mac book pro has no issues.

Comment: Sir main thing if Device not simulator. if device working great then Why you are taking this too much serious.

Comment: It is because I test my apps much more often than on the sim than on an actua device

Answer (score 1):

May be this solution from apple's support community will help you.

via:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/8883401?messageID=8883401#8883401?messageID=8883401

System Preferences -> Sound -> Sound Effects
Check (turn on) "Play user interface sound effects"

Comment: Like I mentioned, I ALREADY TRIED that.

Comment: I am sorry didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other Mac computers, the Mac Pro 2013 does not feature a built-in microphone. Because of this, the initialization the iOS simulator's audio session might fail.

You could solve this by connecting a microphone to the Mac Pro, e.g. by plugging in an USB headset (and then restarting the simulator).